# why is following code giving Abort signal from abort(3) (SIGABRT)

Tags: c++

I am trying to count the number of occurances of each letter in an string

why is Abort signal from abort(3) (SIGABRT) occurring  in my code

following is my code implementation

```
void result()
{
    string a,b,c;
    cin>>a>>b>>c;
    int  x[26]={0},i,j;
    
    for(i=0;i<a.size();i++)
    {
        j=a[i]-'a';
        x[j]++;
    }
    cout<<"YES";
    return;   
}
```

Comment: Run it line by line in a debugger with the input you gave it and see what it does exactly.

Comment: `j` is calculated from user input.   Accessing `x[j]` (in `x[j]++`) will give undefined behaviour if `j` is not between `0` and `25` inclusive.     Calling `abort()` is one possible consequence of that.

Comment: To reproduce your example we need to see the input you gave. As Peter stated your code doesn't work if the input contains any character outside the range a - z, e.g. special characters or upper case characters. To help us reproduce and understand the problem you are facing it would be best to hardcode the input you are working with, e.g. `a = "...";`